# How can i configure a project in gerrit using pygerrit2 GerritRestAPI

Tags: python, git, gerrit

I am using pygerrit2 to create a project in gerrit, I am planning to use    /projects/projectname/config endpoint to configure the project. Has anybody tried using these endpoints, I am having tough time to configure the same as I always get unexpected keyword argument error though i pass the correct data as described in https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#config-input